# Download C++ reference

Tags: documentation, c++, manpage

I'm learning C++ and are currently for some weeks without consistently working Internet connection. I search a (ASCII) terminal searchable & readable C++ documentation. Today I e. g. searched for c_str() reference and couldn't find anything in Ubuntu default man pages.

I'm thankful for any tips and hints

Comment: If this is just generically "where can I download a C++ reference", it might be better off on stackoverflow.  But if you specifically want one on Ubuntu, perhaps it's ok here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can install [`libstdc++6-4.5-doc`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libstdc++6-4.5-doc) to get the manuals for the GNU c++ library, and then [`man std_basic_string`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man3/std_basic_string.3cxx.html) tells you about the contents of that class.

You may ask: how should I know to look in that particular manpage?  Well, what you want is the `-k` (keyword) argument to man:

```
mbp@joy% man -k c_str
....
std_basic_streambuf (3cxx) - (unknown subject)
std_basic_string (3cxx) - (unknown subject)
std_basic_stringbuf (3cxx) - (unknown subject)
std_basic_stringstream (3cxx) - (unknown subject)
```

and then you can ask man for one of those particular pages.

Or, of course, if you search the web (more thoroughly than I did), you might be able to find a PDF of the standard library definition.

Comment: I found another useful way to integrate documentation into my preferred IDE: http://shinnok.com/rants/2011/07/19/linux-man-pages-integration-with-qt-creator/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at c++-annotations, which comes in a number of different formats, and is available from the software center.

Comment: I installed it using the USC natty and can't find it. How can I start it? I feel little bit stupid asking this question...

Comment: You don't "Start" it :). The docs are usually in /usr/share/c++-annotations (if I remember correctly).

Comment: But in general, how do you find documentation you installed?  There's a bit of a gap, but in general either run `yelp` (a doc viewing gui) or just look in `/usr/share/doc`.  Would be nice if it came up in the menu.

Comment: I added an alias to my global bashrc → alias c='less /usr/share/doc/c++-annotations/cplusplus.txt.gz'

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ reference residing at cppreference.com can be downloaded as an archive of HTML pages: http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives

Although this thread is quite old, this link might be useful for others who find it in SERP (as I did).