# How can I know which version of the C++ "standard library" is installed?

Tags: application-development, development, c++, documentation

I would like to install the C++ standard library documentation (following the answers in [Download C++ reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62173/download-c-reference)) but I do not know which version of library is installed in my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire up synaptic and search for libstdc++ and see which version is installed, or run `apt-cache search -n libstdc++` to see what versions are known, then you can check which one(s) are installed with `apt-cache policy libstdc++-XXXX`

Comment: This method won't work if he installed g++ from source

Comment: @tachyons, then he wouldn't be asking the question ;)

Comment: lol enough said

Answer (score 12):

Simple way to find the version of C++ standard library is

```
gcc --version
```

Hope this helps

Comment: doesn't mean that the c++ library is installed